# Is counter predefined in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I did some research and I couldn't understand what is 'Counter' ? is it predefined in js/jquery ? or is it a css property ?

```
$('.count').each(function () {
$(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
}, {
    duration: 4000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function (now) {
        $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Don't think there is any such property..

Comment: It is a name given by the programmer to store the count, so that jQuery can then animate it to the value given in the element's text.

Comment: As the others said, it's not an existing property. More specifically, the dev is creating the property using jQuery's `prop()` method with this part: `$(this).prop('Counter',0)`. `prop()` can either be used as a getter or a setter, in this instance it's a setter, setting a Counter property of 0.

Comment: thanx guys! I really appreciate it.